# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST / PATCH / DELETE

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

I have created manually some routes for customizing purposes.

**Here is my code:**

```
Route::post('/dashboard/show-all-notifications', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'showAllNotifications']);
```

**Form**

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>['App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@showAllNotifications']]) !!}
   {!! Form::submit('Show all notifications', ['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block']) !!}   
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**DashboardController**

```
public function showAllNotifications(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $notifications = Auth::user()->notifications;
        return view('dashboard.showAllNotifications',compact('notifications'));
    }
    else
    {
        return abort(404);
    }
}
```

It's showing me this error when I enter `URL(GET request)` in the browser but it working on the `POST / PATCH / DELETE` Form request. I need something like if the request is `GET`, the return to `404 not found.`

**Does anyone know the solution to this error ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accessing a post route directly from browser url causes this error. you can use either `Route::any()` or `Route::match()` to handle this kind of situation. and then you can check for request method. if it's your desired one, do something, otherwise abort to 404.

```
public function showAllNotifications(Request $request) 
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        //do something
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

and for your information, adding -r or --resource while creating a controller won't solve your issue. those options are for adding methods for crud operations. your own methods and routes have nothing to do with resource.

Comment: I tried before knowing that it works. But I am wrong. NOT WORKED! I retry this again.

Comment: it's not working?? i have tested before answering and it's working fine for me.

Comment: update your question with controller code so that i can check what are you doing.

Comment: and i can see a route mismatch here. in your question the route is `'/user/show-all-notifications'` but in the error exception it's `'/dashboard/show-all-notifications'`. are you using two separate routes??

Comment: how are you entering the get request?? writing down the url in the browser or using get request in the form??

Comment: Yes entering the url

Comment: can you check changing the url like `Route::any('/dashboard/show-all-notifications', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'showAllNotifications']);` if the controller condition actually works.

Comment: WORKED!! Thank you very much.

Comment: glad that helped. i have updated my answer. mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: yes it worked for I manually created Routes and Controllers, but what about `/logout` Route?. It is the default set URL by Laravel.