# How do I get iterations value in Laravel blade @each?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

From [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#control-structures), I changed this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <li>{{ $loop->iteration }}</li>
        <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
        <li>{{ $user->email }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Into:

```
<ul>  
    @each('user.list', $users, 'user', 'user.empty')
</ul>
```

**list.blade.php**

```
<li>{{ $loop->iteration }}</li>
<li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
<li>{{ $user->email }}</li>
```

**empty.blade.php**

```
<li>There is no user is users.</li>
```

But, I get an error "Undefined variable: loop" in `{{ $loop->iteration }}`

**So, is there any way to get iteration in @each?**

Comment: "I get an error" is not a helpful description of the problem.

Comment: Error is simply "Undefined variable: loop"

Comment: Laravel 5.1 was released more than 5 years ago; assuming you aren't using such ancient software, ensure that you're looking at current documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-views-for-collections):

> Views rendered via `@each` do not inherit the variables from the parent view. If the child view requires these variables, you should use `@foreach` and `@include` instead.

So your code will not inherit the `$loop` variable from the parent view, which is handling the looping.

Something like this might work:

```
@if (count($users)
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        @include("user.list", compact("user", "loop"))
    @endforeach
@else
    @include("user.empty")
@endif
```

Comment: OK, I got the point. @miken32 Can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64421225/the-get-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-post-patch. Although, I accepted the answer to my own question, but now I faced the same error at `/logout` route.